# Jquery window.open get URL before close

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, window

Can anyone tell me, if its possible to get the URL of a window.open window, if i make a window.close and the person press the close button(window.close), how do i get the last url he was on? Right before it closed?

Comment: If not same domain and user navigates, that's not possible for obvious security purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // This will get you the current url
```

in your window.close method call.

Comment: function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.dk", "", "width=200,height=100", window.location);
    
var pathname = window.location.href;
var url_popup = window.close(pathname);
console.log(url_popup);
} this is my code, but the console.log just return "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it. links.php:12
undefined "

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think you can do that. Its like closing a seperate tab ie. a totally different window. And you should not have the semi-colon after "google.dk". 

So basically you can close the window you are currently in but not other windows.

Comment: But before i use window.close() on the window, can i get the url on that window? That should be possible?

Comment: Don't you already know the url... its google.dk or what ever you have in window.open()